# MobX - Pass parameter to action as observable to change observable value?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have a MobX store, and a react native class setup and working, but not as intended. I have a list of observable user preferences in the `UserPreferencesStore` like this:

```
class UserPreferencesStore {
    @observable userPreferences = {
        receive_upvotes_mail: 0,
        receive_answers_mail: 0,
        receive_comments_mail: 1
    }
}
```

In the react native class, I want to update the above observables based on onPress of `TouchableHighlight` like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressPreference('receive_upvotes_mail')}>
    <Image source={require('images/Email.png')}
           style={UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.receive_upvotes_mail == 1 && styles.active} />
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressPreference('receive_answers_mail')}>
    <Image source={require('images/Email.png')}
           style={UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.receive_answers_mail == 1 && styles.active} />
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressPreference('receive_comments_mail')}>
    <Image source={require('images/Email.png')}
           style={UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.receive_comments_mail == 1 && styles.active} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

and here is the `onPressPreference` action to update the observables that does not work...

```
@action onPressPreference = (preferenceName) => {
    // alert(preferenceName);
    UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.preferenceName = UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.preferenceName == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The `preferenceName` parameter gets passed perfectly, as the alert shows it, but it does not seem to work when "appended" here `UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences.preferenceName` to update the passed preference observable store value.

However, If I create 3 actions, one for each preference, and trigger them onPress, then it works and the observable updates the value correctly in the store, but it's a lot of code repeated, and I really want to get it to work with the passed parameter to a single action.

Any idea how to get the passed parameter to work with the single action to update the respective observable's value?

Comment: Your question is about ECMAScript, actually, not about MobX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation to access a property with variable name.
`UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences[preferenceName] = UserPreferencesStore.userPreferences[preferenceName] == 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. Learned something new today :)